# IPAD ONLY : Bootstrap grid element wrap to next line despite values adding up to 12

Tags: ios, google-chrome, ipad, safari

I have three elements in my row, all of which have the class col-sm-4.  On desktop and on the chrome dev tools device toolbar everything works fine.  But when I view on my ipad, it does not behave correctly.

```
<div class="row fix">
  <div class="col-sm-4">
  <div class="col-sm-4">
  <div class="col-sm-4">
</div>
```

How it looks on ipad:

[image]

How it should look:

[image]

Bootstrap version 3.3.7. I tested on both chrome and safari on my ipad.  iOS version 10.2

Comment: Is there any additional relevant code? I'm not seeing what may be the issue with three standard Bootstrap .col-sm-4's. Hard to say what the elements contained within the columns may or may not be doing to contribute to this issue.

Comment: @mdlanglais no thats pretty much all the code I have. Yeah i dont really see what the issue is either, it works perfectly fine when i use the chrome dev tools responsive mode and set it to ipad.

Comment: But what are the contents of the columns? In your screenshots above there are labels and input fields. Can you revise your code above to include them? Any styling applied to these elements that might be overriding what Bootstrap is trying to do and upsetting the layout? If I had a little more to go on, I could tinker with it some.